# installing vesta control panel no my aws ec2 and showing errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, async-await

I am installing vesta control panel on my aws ec2 when I started installation on putty
and when I try to run this command *bash vst-install.sh*

```
It's showing error unable to locate some files, Any solution?
E: Unable to locate package rssh
E: Unable to locate package vesta
E: Unable to locate package vesta-nginx
E: Unable to locate package vesta-php
E: Unable to locate package vesta-ioncube
E: Unable to locate package vesta-softaculous
Error: apt-get install failed
```

I want to complete installation of vesta cp on my aws ec2 and I wanna host my website for first time on aws